# Python script not starting on boot

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, boot

The aim:

- Start a python scrip on booting a RaspberryPi-3B with no connections to a PC

What has been done:

- I have followed the procedure as outlines in this post: https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Launch-Python-script-on-startup/?ALLSTEPS

The problem:

1. The python script will not start properly during boot
2. Once I plug in my LAN cable, **the python script starts perfectly**.  This is, in my case, not an option. The python script needs to start with not "lan cable initiated system"

Other info:

This is the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# OS modules #########################################################
import time
# GPIO Pin settings ##################################################
import RPi.GPIO
RPi.GPIO.setmode(RPi.GPIO.BCM)

iLED1 = 21
RPi.GPIO.setup(iLED1,RPi.GPIO.OUT)
#######################################################################
def LED(iPin,bStatus):
    RPi.GPIO.output(iPin,bStatus)

bProgramLoop = True
bLEDState = False
while (bProgramLoop == True):

    if (bLEDState == False):
        LED(iLED1,True)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        bLEDState = True

    if (bLEDState == True):
        LED(iLED1,False)
        time.sleep(0.3)
        bLEDState = False
```

This is the line added to "sudo crontab -e"

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/Misha/DataLogger/V1/launcher.sh >/home/pi/Misha/DataLogger/V1/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

'launcher.sh' has the following entries

```
#!/bin/sh
# launcher.sh

cd /
cd home/pi/Misha/DataLogger/V1
sudo python Test.py
cd /
```

the "launcher.sh" script has the following properties added to it:

```
sudo chmod 777 launcher.sh
```

and checking it with "sh launcher.sh" starts the Test.py script fine.

Comment: could you show us your code and the file/cronjob/script that calls your python code as well?

Comment: @matyas, thanks for your reply, I have added info. With regards to my python script. It is a long script and I am not sure it will be of any use if I added any of it in here. The python script runs perfectly when started from the terminal.

Comment: does the python script perform any operations  that require an internet connection? That would seem to me like the most obvious cause.

Comment: no, not at all as far as i know. I ssh onto the pi. the only thing it requires to operate are the sensors, that are connected via i2c interface. i do import the time module and use time.time. can any of these things cause issues?

Comment: in theory no. Do you have any part in the script that says try... catch Exception as e: ? Maybe an internet unrelated exception gets silenced somewhere in your code. Are you able to run the same script on your pc with no internet connection?

Comment: I have a try function that I put in way back to help me troubleshoot and ensure proper pin cleanup when something goes wrong. I am not sure if some of them may screw with the boot?

Comment: Are your script executed at user login or at startup?
Please keep in mind that on startup no enviroment variables are set (because the deamons are started not in a user enviroment).

Comment: @Stefan. Honestly, your question is above my understanding of boot sequencing. How would I check? I have followed the steps outlines in the link above to the T. I was under the impression using crontab the way outlines in the link if for boot, not login. Also as mentioned, the program does seem to start. When I look at the crontab logs, there is stuff in there, but if I could guess its being interrupted and/or stopped by some booting process. I have tired running the python script on start on RPi2B's as well. all of them seem to only start once the lan cable is plugged in.

Comment: looks like your script is in "/home/pi/". This means that you executing it as user "pi". On what peripherals your script is working? For example: The UART (ttySxxx, ttyUSBxx) are mapped into the /dev/ filesystem as a file. To open, write, read you need rights. These rights are connected to the users. Starting python at boot means that it's runs without being connected to a user.

Comment: @Stefan. would you suggest moving the python script and all the custom modules I made out of "/home/pi/" and into where? What are good practices here, should I make a new directory, and if so where?

Comment: I dont understand why I am having this issue. A lot of people must have tried and done this? what makes my case different? Would removing log in completely help? I have no issue doing this as the system is never connected over the net anyway

Comment: Have you tried giving the python interpreter a complete path?  Like `sudo /usr/bin/python MasterDataLogger.py` (have a look at the output of `type python` first to find out the correct path).

Comment: Misha what is your programm doing? For explanation: at boot cron is started as deamon. If you are using secure linux a extra user for cron is created. You can check this at the start of the cron deamon. I do not know if your using systemV or system D to start the cron deamon. This deamon starts your script. Because the script is started from cron it inheritates its rights + environmental variables(they are set by the user).
There is a boot order at system start. Are you sure that all network services you may rely on are started before cron is started?

Comment: I have stripped it down to the bare core. The program reads sensor data from a EY88 sensor board via i2c. I have used the adafruit i2c libraries to talk to the various chips. It then does some elementary data processing and stores the data in a .csv format. Honestly, I dont know when all the network services are started and in what sequence. This is way way out of my knowledge base. Is there a way to start the python scrip once a few seconds after we know for sure system boot is fully complete.

Comment: a strange thing is that the python script is started, without question, "during/mid/after" boot for a brief time. it is then interrupted and stops with no error or any message. I got this from the cron log file

Comment: @Alfe, I tried what you suggested. "type python" returns "/usr/bin/python", "sudo /usr/bin/python MasterDataLogger.py" returns "...[Errno 2]...no such file in the directory". I have not really put shebangs in my python scripts, i know this is probably a bad habbit. can this be the root of issues?

Comment: try "sudo /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Misha/DataLogger/V1/MasterDataLogger.py"

Comment: You might want to `cd` into the correct directory you expect to be in prior to calling python.  The missing file could be the `/usr/bin/python` *or* your `MasterDataLogger.py` *or* a file your script tries to open.

Comment: @Stefan, your suggestion starts the script fine. 

I have(or am busy) updated my question above, and a python script that is super short and has the exact same issues.

Comment: @Alfe, for some reason when I tried it again now, i did not have any issues. not sure. thanks though!!!

Comment: anyone got any ideas please?